# Editing an entry in a database using PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to edit an entry in the database through the `edit` button on my HTML page. The page `showData.php` prints out a table and shows all the entries of the database in the `patients` table combined with two buttons `delete` and `edit` in separate columns with each row. 
When I press the Edit button, the page redirects to `updateData.php`. Here we can update any field except `patientID`. After clicking `modify` button it redirects to `edit.php` where it performs the action by applying the query to the database and then goes back again to the page `showData.php`.

My problem is that when I click `Modify` it goes back to the `showData.php` without actually updating the database table. Pictures are attached for convenience.

Here is the code:

**showData.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        body {

        }
    </style>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    try{
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=bbdb", "$username", "$password");
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmn = $conn->prepare("Select * from patients order by patientID;");
        $stmn->execute();
        $result = $stmn->fetchAll();

        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";

        echo "<thread>
            <tr>
                <th scope='col'>Patient ID</th>
                <th scope='col'>Name</th>
                <th scope='col'>Blood Group</th>
                <th scope='col'>Email</th>
                <th scope='col'>Address</th>
                <th scope='col'>Delete</th>
                <th scope='col'>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thread>";

        foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['patientID'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['p_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['p_bloodGroup'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['p_email'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['p_address'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td> <a href='delete.php?patientID=" . $row['patientID'] . "'>Delete</a></td>";
            echo "<td> <a href='updateData.php?patientID=" . $row['patientID'] . " &p_name=" . $row['p_name'] . " &p_bloodGroup=" . $row['p_bloodGroup'] . " &p_email=" . $row['p_email'] . " &p_address=" . $row['p_address'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";

    }catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e){
        echo "Connection Failed" , $e->getMessage();
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `showData.php` visualization:

[image: dataTable]

**updateData.php**

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    try{
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=bbdb", "$username", "$password");
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        session_start();

        if(!isset($_SESSION['loginUsername'])){
            header("location: bbIndex.php");
        }

        $id = $_GET['patientID'];
        $name = $_GET['p_name'];
        $bloodGroup = $_GET['p_bloodGroup'];
        $email = $_GET['p_email'];
        $address = $_GET['p_address'];


    }catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e){
        echo "Connection Failed" , $e->getMessage();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        body {
        }
    </style>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form action="edit.php" method="post" class="was-validated">

            <div class="w-50 p-3">
                <label>PatientID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pID" size="30" placeholder="<?php echo $id ?>" readonly="" required="true">
                <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="w-50 p-3">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname" size="30" maxlength="225" value="<?php echo $name ?>" required="true">
                <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="w-50 p-3">
                <label>Blood Group</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pBG" size="30" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo $bloodGroup ?>" required="true">
                <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="w-50 p-3">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="pemail" size="30" maxlength="225" value="<?php echo $email ?>" required="true">
                <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="w-50 p-3">
                <label>Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pAdd" size="30" maxlength="225" value="<?php echo $address ?>" required="true">
                <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Modify</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-light">Reset</button> 

        </form>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `updateData.php` visualization:

[image: updateData]

**edit.php**

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";

        try{
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=bbdb", "$username", "$password");
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $id = $_POST['pID'];
            $name = $_POST['pname'];
            $bloodGroup = $_POST['pBG'];
            $email = $_POST['pemail'];
            $address = $_POST['pAdd'];

            $stmn = $conn->prepare("update patients set p_name='$name', p_bloodGroup='$bloodGroup', p_email='$email', p_address='$address' where patientID = '$id';");
            $stmn->execute();
            header("refresh:0;url=showData.php");

        }catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e){
        echo "Connection Failed" , $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Remove the space in all your `" &p`

Comment: You are not using prepared statements correctly. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Dharman how wud u suggest I change it to invulnerable?

Comment: @RiggsFolly where do you mean?

Comment: Please read https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement

Comment: In this line `echo "<td> <a href='updateData.php?patientID=" . $row['patientID'] . "&p_name=" . $row['p_name'] . "&p_bloodGroup=" . $row['p_bloodGroup'] . "&p_email=" . $row['p_email'] . "&p_address=" . $row['p_address'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just change `placeholder` attribute to `value` attribute for input $id in updateData.php.**

Your value of $id which you are using in `WHERE` clause in your query is not passing from updateData.php to edit.php because `POST` method takes whatever there is in `value` attribute and `POST` it but in your case, you are using `placeholder` attribute. Rest of the information is passing except your $id so that's why your query is not outputting what you want.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's hope this isn't real patient data. By sending all fields as part of the `href` to the `updateData.php`, you do absolutely no validation and a malicious user could easily insert any data into the table just by typing their own URL in.

At a very minimum you should just pass the patient-id to `updateData.php`, and let it read the information from the database.

How are you not running into problems when passing data containing spaces to `updateData.php`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. This is just a demo project bht I would like to practice your idea. Also I removed the spaces so it's running fine.

Comment: What I meant was, when your patient name is "Dave Greenfield" for example, that has spaces in it, and I can't see that you url-encode it for the link, so I'm surprised it doesn't give you errors in the link or at the very least lose the parameters that come after the name.

Comment: how would you have written it to avoid this if it were?

Comment: I'd just pass the patient-id in the link (or I'd actually use a miniature form and send it using POST), and let the destination code read the details from the database to edit them. If you _have_ to do it the way you have, use `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` to get around any unsafe characters.